# Convergence range of Binomial Expansions with square unknowns?

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, absolute-value, binomial-theorem

So the binomial expansion of $\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{a^2+x^2}\right)^{5/2}$ would converge for $\left|\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right|<1.$

Would this not mean that

$-1<\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$?

But isn't $0\leq\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}$, and so shouldn't the convergence range just be $0\leq\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$? Also wouldn't the inequality $-1<\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$'s left hand side produce a square-rooting problem?

Comment: well $0\leq\frac{a^2}{x^2}$ is always true for $x, a$ reals, so  $-1< \frac{a^2}{x^2}$ and $0\leq\frac{a^2}{x^2}$ are trivially equivalent, because either way$-1<\frac{a^2}{x^2}<0$ is never true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Regarding your first question: ... shouldn't the convergence range just be $0\leq\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$?

Note the following sets are equal:

\begin{align*}
\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\left|\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right|<1\right\}
&=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:-1<\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1\right\}\\
&=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:0\leq \frac{x^2}{a^2}<1\right\}\\
&=\left(-|a|,|a|\right)
\end{align*}

This means whenever an element $x$ is in one of the sets it is also in all the other sets. So, you are free to choose the representation which seems to be the most convenient for your needs.

> Regarding your second question: ... wouldn't the inequality $-1<\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{a^2}<1$'s left hand side produce a square-rooting problem?

No, since it belongs to you to do correct manipulations with this double inequality in order to determine the range of validity for $x$.

Comment: As I forgot to clarify that my question is actually two sub-questions, I appreciate your answer in that it recognises this and deals with them individually.

Comment: @user98937: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Comment: As I forgot to clarify that my question is actually two sub-questions, I appreciate your answer in that it recognises this and deals with them individually. Also, I am not sure whether you've either missed out the squares in the final line of your response to my first sub-question, i.e. shouldn't it be $-\sqrt{|a|^2}<x<\sqrt{|a|^2}$, or there shouldn't be the square roots there, i.e.  $-|a|<x<|a|$ ?

Comment: @user98937:  Typo  corrected. Thanks.